# Common denominator (column) in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a website that has products added to categories. Those categories are hierarchically ranked. So a product is a member of a category and all of the parents of this category. We have a search index table that looks like this:

```
product_id | category_level_1 | category_level_2 | category_level_3 | property_a | property_b
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1          | category1        | category2        | category3        | 1          | 2
2          | category1        | category2        | category4        | 1          | 3
```

If I run a query on the product search index table filtering on some properties (eg propery_a and property_b) I also want to know what the lowest common denominator category is. In the above example category2.

I have a working query that will return a resultset to my application including the columns category_level_1, category_level_2 and category_level_3. While looping through the resultset I can determine the lowest common denominator category.

However, if I could determine the lowest common denominator in the first query, this would save me a lot of data transport (the category tree is up to 9 levels in real life). Does anyone have a suggestion how to determine the common category in a query that also filters on the properties (WHERE property_a = 1)?

**Based on the answer of ARTM this is what my solution finally was:**

The reality is more complex but you put me on the right path! Thanks!  The query regarding the properties can be very complex: WHERE (property_a = 1 AND (Property_2 = 2 or Peroperty_2) = 3 AND Property_3 = 4) etc. etc.
Lets call this "property_query".

I got this to work:

```
SELECT product_id, category as common_category FROM ( SELECT Product_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS productCount FROM <tablename> WHERE <property_query>)) A INNER JOIN (  
        select count(*) as categoryCount , category
    from (select category_level_1 as cat, from <tablename> WHERE <property_query>
        union all select category_level_2, from <tablename> WHERE <property_query>
        union all select category_level_3, from <tablename> WHERE <property_query>)c
            group by cat )  B  ON B.categoryCount = A.productCount
```

Now I have to test it for performance....

Comment: Please show the query you have attempted.

Comment: And show us the expected result!

Comment: I haven't attempted anything yet since I don't know how. The current (simplified) query is select * from products where  property_a = 1.

Comment: An expected result would be:
product_id | common_category
1                | category2
2                | category2

Comment: @PeterdeBruijn Please leave a comment under my answer about how the performance went so I get a notification as to how slow/fast it's been.

Comment: The performance was bad (almost twice as slow). I reverted to the original query :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the union of all category columns where property_a is what you're looking for, and get the count grouped by category. Then you can join on the other inner select where the count of rows with search criteria is the same as count grouped by each category.

```
SELECT product_id, cat AS CommonDeno
FROM (
select COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY property_a) AS ProductCountWithProperty_A
, product_id
, pr.property_a
from yourTable
) A 
INNER JOIN (select count(*) as catCount
, cat
    from (
        select category_level_1 as cat, property_a as p from yourTable
        union all select category_level_2, property_a from yourTable
        union all select category_level_3, property_a from yourTable
    ) c
    where c.p = 1
    group by cat
) i on i.catCount = A.ProductCountWithProperty_A
AND A.property_a = 1
```

Comment: The reality is more complex but you put me on the right path! Thanks!  The query regarding the properties can be very complex (WHERE property_a = 1 AND (Property_2 = 2 or Peroperty_2) = 3 AND Property_3 = 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you needn't loop over result set in the second step.

```
with result(product_id,  category_level_1 , category_level_2 , category_level_3, property_a , property_b) as
(
--your first query here
)
select denominator=
   case min(category_level_1) when max(category_level_1) then min(category_level_1)  + 
      case min(category_level_2) when max(category_level_2) then min(category_level_2)  +
        case min(category_level_3) when  max(category_level_3) then min(category_level_3) else '' end else '' end end
from result
having min(category_level_1) = max( category_level_1)
```

Next if you are on sql 2014 then you may incorporate this logic into first query with windowing `max() over(), min() over()`

Comment: I have tried this solution but the columns category_level_1, 2 and 3 are Guids. So I can't use min/max on them...

Comment: Just cast them to char(36) in first query.